# How to call INCRBY and EXPIRE most efficiently in Redis

Tags: java, lua, redis, lettuce

For a collection of aggregate objects that may or may not already exist in Redis, I'd like to call INCRBY and EXPIRE on them. From my reading, it seems using either [MULTI](https://redis.io/commands/multi) or [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval) is the way to go. Following the [INCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/incrby) and [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire) operations on the aggregate objects, I need to get back the updated counts of each aggregate that's returned from the INCRBY operation. I'm using the Lettuce client and looking for an example of how best to do this. For simplicity, assume the aggregate object is something like:

```
public class Aggregate {
  private String id; // key in Redis
  private Long count; // INCRBY operates on
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Well, it is hard to give you a definitive answer because the result will heavily depend on multiple factors:

1. **Network latency**. Data roundtrips are often much longer than processing itself. And if you need `n` commands, these times multiply.
2. **Number of threads**. They won't help you with latency, but can saturate your connection and give you a lot of throughput.
3. **Need for atomicity**. When you only call `incrby` and then `expire` from writers and `get` from readers, the worst thing could happen is... nothing, I guess. But if there are other readers who modify, but not expire, then you can expire wrongly (writer1>`incrby`, writer2>`set`, writer1>`expire`). If you're sure you only have the first type of writers then you can save on atomicity.

And also you may need to optimize either for throughput or latency. And specifically for your environment. As you will see later, different approaches would come ahead in different setups.

### Contenders

#### Atomical

1. `EVAL` (incrby, expire). We issue a Lua script that does the job. Pros: Redis guarantees atomicity for Lua. Cons: we need to send script body over and over again.
2. `EVAL` (get, setex). The same, but we can use different commands to do the job. These would be called with 'gs' at the end in the benchmark.
3. `EVALSHA`. We can first load script body and then only send digest of it. Pros: less bytes in a command. Cons: need to be sure no one suddenly `SCRIPT FLUSH` your script away, also with a lot of scripts lookup times may increase. I expected this to be a clear winner, but the script was small enough to not be a burden for connection.
4. `MULTI`. We can issue commands in a transaction. This time Redis would stage them until you issue `EXEC`. It is a significant overhead and stays here only for completeness.

#### Non-atomical

1. Naive. We can just issue one command and then the other. Pros: simple code.
2. Async. We can leverage luttuce's async API to skip waiting for the result of `EXPIRE`. Pros: feeling smart.
3. Async_flush. We can try to further optimize and make use of [command pipelining](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Pipelining-and-command-flushing). Pros: saving bandwidth, but only for large batches. Cons: you need a dedicated connection and initialize it accordingly.

### The benchmark

Here is [the code](https://github.com/Imaskar/RedisBatchesBenchmark).

You really should run it yourself to optimize for your needs. I noticed some options defined in the code are ignored, so make use of command line parameters.

#### Single thread

Still, I will post my results. I ran it with 1 thread for 3 different connection types: local unix socket, local TCP, remote TCP. Unfortunately, remote host had a much weaker single thread performance of CPU, so I have to post it's local results for a reference. Unfortunately there is a lot of things running on this remote, so its results may be compromised.

```
Benchmark                          (address)   Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async        socket     thrpt   50  39722.167 ±  796.830  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async_flush  socket     thrpt   50  37973.392 ±  239.880  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalsha      socket     thrpt   50  35697.480 ±  216.258  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.eval         socket     thrpt   50  34616.848 ±  238.412  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalshags    socket     thrpt   50  32642.795 ±  129.305  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalgs       socket     thrpt   50  31679.147 ±  150.264  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.naive        socket     thrpt   50  20935.985 ±  124.092  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.multi        socket     thrpt   50  19133.523 ±   72.581  ops/s

RedisBatchesBenchmark.async        localhost  thrpt   50  39179.742 ± 1457.819  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async_flush  localhost  thrpt   50  33647.195 ±  295.427  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalsha      localhost  thrpt   50  30679.493 ±  109.669  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.eval         localhost  thrpt   50  29680.750 ±  161.762  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalshags    localhost  thrpt   50  28069.431 ±  158.887  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalgs       localhost  thrpt   50  27142.783 ±   69.314  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.naive        localhost  thrpt   50  17934.587 ±  152.859  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.multi        localhost  thrpt   50  15220.863 ±   32.219  ops/s

RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalsha      remote     thrpt   50   4001.585 ±   12.200  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalgs       remote     thrpt   50   3966.271 ±   16.590  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async_flush  remote     thrpt   50   3867.448 ±  153.232  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.eval         remote     thrpt   50   3622.256 ±  246.454  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalshags    remote     thrpt   50   3607.975 ±  251.802  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async        remote     thrpt   50   2681.453 ±   13.451  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.naive        remote     thrpt   50   2014.806 ±    5.630  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.multi        remote     thrpt   50   1344.477 ±    3.375  ops/s
------------
Remote host:
Benchmark                          (address)   Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
RedisCommandPacking.naive          socket     thrpt   25  11605,994 ±  368,055  ops/s
RedisCommandPacking.naive          localhost  thrpt   25   9477,190 ±  239,817  ops/s
```

**What do we see here?**

- Not waiting for expire result is fast, but when we add latency (mere
  0.194ms ping) `EVALSHA` comes ahead. Notice how much even minimal latency affects performance of such speedy operations. Even taking into account slower CPU, we lost 5x.
- Two commands are not enough to get a boost from manual flushing (but
  note, that we don't wait for expire result. It may be different if we
  would).
- This script body is small enough to compete with digest.
- incrby+expire is better than get+setex.
- Multi is at the bottom as expected.
- Error value of async is very high, meaning performance differs a lot from call to call. Not a good thing when you care for maximum latency.

#### Two threads

```
Benchmark                       (address)      Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async_flush  socket     thrpt   50  97904.168 ± 2497.354  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async        socket     thrpt   50  95156.162 ± 1556.060  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalsha      socket     thrpt   50  66418.081 ± 1236.815  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.eval         socket     thrpt   50  63202.798 ± 1807.753  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalshags    socket     thrpt   50  55259.215 ± 1771.674  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalgs       socket     thrpt   50  54047.418 ± 1143.995  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.naive        socket     thrpt   50  37771.010 ± 1378.210  ops/s

RedisBatchesBenchmark.async        localhost  thrpt   50  71901.709 ± 1041.603  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async_flush  localhost  thrpt   50  66513.162 ± 1353.913  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalsha      localhost  thrpt   50  52052.253 ± 1087.449  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.eval         localhost  thrpt   50  50806.715 ± 1220.019  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalshags    localhost  thrpt   50  47248.272 ± 1096.685  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalgs       localhost  thrpt   50  44633.113 ± 1829.829  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.naive        localhost  thrpt   50  35757.586 ± 1455.315  ops/s

RedisBatchesBenchmark.eval         remote     thrpt   50   4030.373 ±   19.535  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async        remote     thrpt   50   4010.730 ±   19.527  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.async_flush  remote     thrpt   50   4004.914 ±   25.449  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalgs       remote     thrpt   50   3983.623 ±   31.027  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalshags    remote     thrpt   50   3978.253 ±   51.875  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.evalsha      remote     thrpt   50   3949.376 ±   52.273  ops/s
RedisBatchesBenchmark.naive        remote     thrpt   50   2015.643 ±   17.920  ops/s
```

**What do we see here?**

- Async got big boost especially on unix socket.
- Async is now very close to async_flush on remote.
- Async_flush is not profitable, taking complications into account.
- Remote results are very close to each other, especially considering measurement error.
- No `MULTI` because it can't be used on shared connection and benchmark should be changed to include it. That will add even more overhead, so won't do it.